# Is the console window in Eclipse limited in lines?

Tags: eclipse, console

Simply as that.

I just need a Yes or No.

And by lines i mean a ridiculous amount of lines(like 1000000000000000 lines for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer size must be between 1000 and 1000000 inclusive or not limited